# How to authorize my google sheets apps script to access the data from the spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-oauth

I am trying to access the data from a range using the following code written in the script editor. The following code shows how I want to access the active sheet. The second line is making the problem.

```
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss  = sss.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

when I run the code. It takes me to the login screen.

[Screenshot showing the request to sign in for authorization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI0a9.png)

When I sign in, it gives me this message without any ACTIONABLE buttons.

> **This app is blocked**
>
> This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To
> keep your account safe, Google blocked this access.

[Screenshot showing the message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwP87.png)

I own the script which is attached to the google sheet also owned by me the same google account.

How to authorize the apps script to access the data?

Comment: Just click on your gmail account on the first image, and allow it will do...

Comment: @KinSiang No it doesn't. That is the issue. When I click the gmail account or signin, it gives me the error screen "This app is blocked" (screenshot in the second image). No actionable item is on the error screen meaning I am blocked at that point.

Comment: You are on a workspace (gsuite) account?

Comment: It seem like you are using personal gmail but cannot allow it, try create another worksheet and test it? It never happen to me

Comment: What happens when you try with a new Spreadsheet?

Comment: Do you see an error in your [OAuth Consent Screen](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent)?

Comment: I am also running into this problem and cannot solve it. I can't even run Google's own "Your First Script" tutorial because of this.